# How to merge content from multiple document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, angular5, jspdf, html2canvas

I have to get the content inside two id and export it to PDF. I did following to get the content.

```
var first_data = document.getElementById("a");
var second_data = document.getElementById("b");
```

When I made console, I get following:

```
<div _ngcontent-c18 id="a">....</div>
<div _ngcontent-c15 id="b">....</div>
```

I have tried following code to display content of first_data

```
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
    const content = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const position = 40;
    doc.addImage(content, 'PNG', 15, position, 108, 160);
    doc.save('test.pdf');
})
```

But now I have second_data as well. How can I merge first_data & second_data and display it to single pdf?

Comment: Maybe put them both in a container together, and call `html2canvas` on the container?

Comment: @CertainPerformance no I can not put both inside single container. they are from different component

Comment: I don’t think html2canvas has a build-in way to do something like that, so I guess your options are either a), merge two separate screenshots together yourself after taking them, or b) wrap both elements into a common container element. (When you say they aren’t in one, then maybe create clones, put those in a container together, and have it take the screenshot of that then.)